# Where to add a where into this SQL statement?

Tags: mysql, sql, count, sql-order-by, where-clause

An old Cake (php) site I've been working on has been pen tested, and I'm trying to find which cart items have been filled up with thousands of items.

The following code works and give me and ordered list of cart items grouped by session in descending order:

```
SELECT *, COUNT(session_code) AS the_count FROM cart_items GROUP BY session_code ORDER BY the_count DESC;
```

What I'd like to do is add a final where into it so I can just get cart items which have over 1000 for the count like so:

(note the code below does not work)

```
SELECT *, COUNT(session_code) AS the_count FROM cart_items GROUP BY session_code WHERE the_count > 1000  ORDER BY the_count DESC;
```

Is is possible to add a where into this for the_count ?

Answer (score 3):

```
SELECT *, COUNT(session_code) AS the_count 
FROM cart_items 
GROUP BY session_code 
HAVING COUNT(session_code) > 1000 
ORDER BY COUNT(session_code) DESC;
```

The key is `HAVING` keyword which allows filtering after `GROUP BY`.

Comment: That's great! Whiles I'm at it, how do I turn the SELECT into a DELETE FROM....? 

Also I have to wait 15 mins before I can accept your answer.